# Work around for unpredictable results when updating a clustered unique index that is not the index specified to be used for SQL Server CDC

Tags: sql, sql-server

When you have a SQL Server table that is enabled for CDC that has one or more Unique Indexes/Primary keys.  If the clustered unique index is not the one specified to be used with CDC and you update the clustered unique index it will produce an __$Seqval that shows the row deleted as the last operation that breaks the get net change function because it will say it will say it doesn't exist when it clearly still does.

I think this is because of how unique clustered indexes are updated (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week---split,-sort,-collapse/)

Does anyone know of a work around for this issue or if there is something I'm doing wrong that would cause this issue to happen.  I tossed a connect item out but I fear that will be a graveyard.

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
    CREATE DATABASE REPO_CDC_ISSUE
GO
USE REPO_CDC_ISSUE
GO
CREATE TABLE TEST_VICTIM(
    TestVictim_ID int identity(1,1),
    ParentVictim_ID int,
    TextDateColumn_CDE char(6),
    DateColumn_DTE date,
    OtherColumnForPosterity char(20),
    untracked int
)

ALTER TABLE TEST_VICTIM
 ADD CONSTRAINT pk_TEST_VICTIM PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (TestVictim_ID)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED  INDEX IDX_TEST_VICTIM_ParentVictim_ID_TextDateColumn_CDE ON TEST_VICTIM(
ParentVictim_ID,TextDateColumn_CDE
)

INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(1,'201401','2015-01-01','30853513',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(2,'201402','2015-01-01','30853513',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(3,'201403','2015-01-01','30853513',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(4,'201404','2015-01-01','30853513',1)

USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [REPO_CDC_ISSUE] ADD FILEGROUP [CDC]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [REPO_CDC_ISSUE] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'REPO_CDC_ISSSUE_CDC', FILENAME = N'D:\DBData01\REPO_CDC_ISSSUE_CDC.ndf' , SIZE = 51200KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%) TO FILEGROUP [PRIMARY]
GO
USE REPO_CDC_ISSUE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
GO

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
    @source_schema = N'dbo'
  , @source_name = N'TEST_VICTIM'
  , @role_name = N'cdc_admin'
  , @capture_instance = N'dbo_TEST_VICTIM' 
  , @supports_net_changes = 1
  , @index_name = N'pk_TEST_VICTIM' 
  , @captured_column_list = N'TestVictim_ID, ParentVictim_ID, TextDateColumn_CDE,DateColumn_DTE,OtherColumnForPosterity' 
  , @filegroup_name = N'PRIMARY';
GO
INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(5,'201301','2013-01-01','30853513',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(6,'201302','2013-01-01','30853513',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(7,'201303','2013-01-01','30853513',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_VICTIM VALUES(8,'201304','2013-01-01','30853513',1)
go
select * 
from cdc.dbo_TEST_VICTIM_ct
go

create table #ARD_CHANGES(
TextDateColumn_CDE  varchar(43) ,
DateColumn_DTE   varchar(40),
TestVictim_ID  int
)

insert into #ARD_CHANGES values ('201301','2013-01-01',6),
('201301','2013-02-18',5)
go
UPDATE pte
SET pte.TextDateColumn_CDE = ARDCHG.TextDateColumn_CDE
   ,pte.DateColumn_DTE = ARDCHG.DateColumn_DTE
FROM TEST_VICTIM pte 
INNER JOIN #ARD_CHANGES ARDCHG
ON pte.TestVictim_ID = ARDCHG.TestVictim_ID

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
select TestVictim_ID ,__$start_lsn,__$seqval,__$operation 
from cdc.dbo_TEST_VICTIM_ct
where TestVictim_ID in (5,6)
order by TestVictim_ID ,__$start_lsn,__$seqval

DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10),
@to_lsn binary(10)

set @from_lsn =sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn ('dbo_TEST_VICTIM') 
set @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn ()


SELECT * 
FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_TEST_VICTIM(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all');

drop table #ARD_CHANGES

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table
@source_schema = N'dbo',
@source_name   = N'TEST_VICTIM',
@capture_instance = N'dbo_TEST_VICTIM'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db
GO
use master 
GO
alter database REPO_CDC_ISSUE SET restricted_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
DROP DATABASE REPO_CDC_ISSUE
```